# How to build msi installer which creates .exe instead of .jar?

Tags: java, gradle, wix

I have some gradle project on java. I know, how to build .exe artifact by Launch4j from .jar. Also I know how to  create .msi installer by gradle plugin 'setup-builder' (uses wixtoolset), which installs project folder with java libs and main .jar file inside. Now I want to combine both points but I can't find information how to realise it. Is it possible? If yes - how to do it?
Or maybe is there other way without wix/launch4j?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inno Setup, which creates an .exe installer. It's very useful because you can include some other program within the installation (like MySQL installer or Java installer). http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: I can't use Inno Setup, because I need .msi, not exe :(